# Hosting Asp.Net Core 3.0 in Azure: HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-3.0

I am trying to host an ASP.NET Core 3.0 API in Azure:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <NeutralLanguage>en-US</NeutralLanguage>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>   
  </PropertyGroup>  

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="3.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.*" />
  </ItemGroup>       

</Project>
```

But when I run de application I get:

```
HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies

Common solutions to this issue:
The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.
Specific error detected by ANCM:
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '3.0.0' was not found. - The following frameworks were found: 2.1.12 at [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App] 2.1.13 at [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App] 2.2.6 at [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App] 2.2.7 at [D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App] You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK. The .NET Core frameworks can be found at: - https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ASP.NET Core 3.0 not currently available for Azure App Service.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#aspnet-core-30-not-currently-available-for-azure-app-service) [Microsoft Docs]

The [preview versions of .NET Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/index?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#deploy-aspnet-core-preview-release-to-azure-app-service) [Microsoft Docs] are available on the Azure service.

Answer (score 8):

The current [picture](https://aspnetcoreon.azurewebsites.net/) is that ASP.NET Core 3.0 is available everywhere (but not the SDK).

Despite this fact, I (seemingly randomly) got a

```
HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies
```

until I realized that activating logging in `web.config` by setting `stdoutLogEnabled` to `true` *without* adjusting the `stdoutLogFile` to `\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout` (as suggested in [Troubleshoot ASP.NET Core on Azure App Service and IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.0)) was the cause of this error message.

Took me some hours to realize this causality.

Comment: you saved me these hours - thank you so much!!

Comment: Also in my case it was arguments="CorrectPathOfDll"

Answer (score 0):

Change this in web.config:

```xml
<handlers>
     <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
```

to this:

```xml
<handlers>
     <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
```

I removed `V2` from this `modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2"` and it works.